# Alfresco - file already exists after file moved to another folder

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, web-scripting

I use Alfresco 4.2.c on a Linux 64bit machine.2.c on a Linux 64bit machine. To insert files on Alfresco i've mapped \192.168.20.101:8080\alfresco as a network drive in Windows XP.

i've developed a webscript in Java that takes as input the nodeRef of a file, then make an update of a metadata and at the end move the file from the initial folder to another folder. It works great and i'm very satiesfied for this!

But i've a strange behaviour: i have a file named for example "fileA" in the folderA, i execute the webscript so the file is moved to folderB.
If i try to insert through the mapped network another file in the folderA named "fileA" Windows says there is already a file named fileA in that folder so i have to cancel the operation...but in the folder i'm sure there is not such file and also if i go into repository i don't see a fileA in the folder A...

Maybe i've to set something particular?
Here is a snippet of code of the webscript:

```
newFileName = oldFileName + "_" + new Date().getTime();
fileFolderService.move(docRef, childRef, newFileName);
```

Comment: I guess you've mapped htttp://*.*.*.*:8080/alfresco/webdav using Alfresco's webdav capabilities, right?
What happens if you Refresh your Folder in Win Explorer after executing your webscript? Maybe, you're running into a Windows Explorer Caching issue...

Comment: i've mapped \192.168.20.101:8080\alfresco...i think this will use CIFS...of course i have refred more and more time the folder but the problem always occur!also if i try 30minutes later! any ideas?

Comment: noop, I don't think that you're running CIFS on 8080. That's normally a "web"-port. it should be 192.168.20.101:8080/alfresco/webdav to use webdav or you can even try to use the VTI module aka Sharepoint protocol.
Pls visit 192.168.20.101:8080/alfresco in your browser & describe what your seeing

Comment: Typing the address 192.168.20.101:8080/alfresco in the browser i see the webapp Alfresco(in which i could login and see the CompanyHome etc...). The same address i use to "Map network drive" in another pc...

Comment: Pls try to mount http://192.168.20.101:8080/alfresco/webdav instead